# Solve $f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)+f\left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}\right)=x$ $\forall x\neq -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Given function $y=f(x)$
such that 
$$f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)+f\left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}\right)=x \quad\forall x\neq -1$$
find $f(x)$ and $f(2007)$.

Comment: No other constraints?  Like "f" is continuous, or anything like that?

Comment: Is $f(x)$ even?

Comment: If you don't have any further conditions on $f$, you cannot find $f(1)$, because neither $\frac{x-3}{x+1}$ nor $\frac{x+3}{x+1}$ can ever be $1$. Hence we cannot find a relation of the form $f(1)+f(b)=c$ for any $b$ and $c$.

Comment: You can solve it if $f$ has to be continuous.

Comment: He starts out with "Given $f(x)$", but I take it he wants any $f$ which has this property.

Comment: sorry caculate $f(x)$ and $f(2007)$

Answer (score 4):

With 
$$f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x-1}-\frac{3}{2}$$
we have
$$a := f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right) = -x-\frac{3}{2}$$
and 
$$b := f\left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}\right)=2x+\frac{3}{2}$$
Therefore the sum is $a+b=x$ and $f(2007)=-\frac{999}{2006}.$

Edit regarding the comments: My function $f(x)\,$ **is a solution** of the functional equation (FE). The road to it was as follows: If the FE is valid for all $x\ne -1\;$ and you plug in large $x$ into the FE, you see that there should be a singularity at $x=1.\;$ Making the ansatz $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x-1}+\cdots$ and playing arround with Maple arrives at the given function.

If the OP has a different function solving the FE, this only shows that there are at least two solutions.

Comment: why do you have $f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x-1}-\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: What do you mean with **why**?

Comment: I'm not seeing where that line comes from either, @gammatester.  It's not a given in the OP's question

Comment: Is that function just an example that matches the required function? If so can you prove that it's the only such function?

Comment: Wow, new vocabulary, ansatz is a nice term for "parameterized  guess".  Thanks~~

Answer (score 3):

Below we show the following

**Claim.** Let $y_0\in\mathbb R$ be arbitrary. Then there exists a continuous function $f\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}\to \mathbb R$ such that 
$$f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right) +f\left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}\right)=x\qquad\text{for all $x\ne -1$}$$
and $f(2007)=y_0$.

---

Let $g_0\colon[1,4]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function with $$\tag0g_0(4)=12+g_0(1).$$
Given a continuous function $g_k\colon[4^{-k},4^{k+1}]\to\mathbb R$, $k\ge 0$, with 
$$\tag1 g_k(4x)=12x+g_k(x)\qquad\text{whenever $x,4x\in[4^{-k},4^{k+1}]$},$$
we can define $g_{k+1}\colon[4^{-k-1},4^{k+2}]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$ g_{k+1}(x)=\begin{cases}g_k(x)&\text{if $4^{-k}\le x\le4^{k+1}$}\\
g_k(4x)-12x&\text{if $4^{-k-1}\le x\le4^{k}$}\\
g_k(x/4)+3x&\text{if $4^{-k+1}\le x \le 4^{k+2}$}
\end{cases}$$
Indeed, the cases cover all of the desired domain, i.e. $$[4^{-k},4^{k+1}]\cup [4^{-k-1},4^{k}] \cup [4^{-k+1},4^{k+2}]= [4^{-k-1},4^{k+2}]$$ if $k\in\mathbb N_0$ and $(1)$ guarantees that the overlapping between the cases is not harmful.
Moreover, whenever $x,4x\in[4^{-k-1},4^{k+2}]$, one of the three cases covers both $x$ and $4x$ so that $(1)$ with $k\leftarrow k+1$ holds. Since $g_{k}$ is the restriction of $g_{k+1}$ to its domain, we can define $g\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$
$$ g(x)=g_k(x)\qquad \text{for any $k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $x\in[4^{-k},4^{k+1}]$}.$$
Then $g$ is continuous and $$\tag2g(4x)=12x+g(x)\qquad \text{for all $x>0$}.$$
Define $h\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ as
$$ h(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{if $x>0$}\\2x-1-g(-x/2)&\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$$
Then we have
$$\tag3h(2x)=4x-1-h(-x)\qquad\text{for all $x\ne0$}. $$
Indeed, this follows for $x>0$ from $$h(2x)+h(-x)=g(2x)+2(-x)-1-g(x/2)\stackrel{(2)}=6x+g(x/2)-2x-1-g(x/2) =4x-1$$
and for $x<0$ from 
$$ h(2x)+h(-x)=4x-1-g(-x)+g(-x)=4x-1.$$

Finally define $f\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}\to \mathbb R$ as
$$ f(x)=h\left(\frac1{x-1}\right).$$
Then for all $x\ne-1$, we have
$$\tag4\begin{align}f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right) +f\left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}\right)&=h\left(-\frac{x+1}{4}\right)+h\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)=x.
\end{align}$$
Vice versa, any $f$ like this allows us to define $h(x)=f(1+\tfrac 1x)$ for $x\ne0$ such that $(4)$ implies $(3)$; then define $g(x)=h(x)$ for $x>0$ by which $(3)$ implies $(2)$; finally define $g_0(x)=g(x)$ for $1\le x\le 4$, by which $2)$ implies $0)$.

So this gives us a large family of solutions, one for each choice of continuous $g_0$ with $(0)$. Specifically, for any $x_0\in[1,4]$ and $y_0\in\mathbb R$, there exists $g_0$ with $g_0(x_0)=y_0$. 
From $f(2007)=h(\frac1{2006})=g(\frac1{2006})$ we find using $(2)$ that $f(2007)$ is a constant plus $g_0(\frac{4^6}{2006})$ and therefore $f(2007)$ can assume any arbitrary value.

---

**Remark:** We cannot expect the solutions to be "more unique" by adding assumptions such as that $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$: That would require that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}h(x)$ exists, which is not possible according to $(3)$.

Comment: Very mathematical answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I get an answer for your question but I am not sure that my answer is unique. I think the exclusivity of solution is still to be proved.

Firstly I make some basic transformation to you origin equation:
$$f(1-\frac{4}{1+x})+f(1+\frac{2}{1+x})=x$$
Let $y=\frac{2}{1+x}$, the equation can be transformed into:
$$f(1-2y)+f(1+y)=\frac{2}{y}-1  \;where \;y\neq 0$$
Again let $m=y+1$:
$$f(3-2m)+f(m)=\frac{3-m}{m-1}$$

> **Here I assume that $f(m)$ has the form of $\frac{cm+d}{am+b}$ after the investigation of above equation**

*This assumption is mostly based on experience rather than strict proof. So it's possible that there exists some solutions where $f(m)$ is not in this form.*

We can reorganize and apply the form to the equation
$$(m-1)((c(3-2m)+d)(am+b)+(cm+d)(a(3-2m))+b))=(3-m)(am+b)(a(3-2m)+b)$$
This is a very long equation. But we can just specific the value of m since this equation holds for all of m.

When $m=1$
$$LHS=0=-(a+b)^2=RHS$$
We can conclude that $a=-b$

When $m=3$, with the knowledge that $a=-b$
$$b(d+9c)=0$$
Because $b \ne 0$(if $b=0$, denominator of $f(x)$ would be $0$ which is impossible) ,so $d=-9c$

We apply $a=-b$ and $d=-9c$ to the original equation.
$$f(3-2m)+f(m)=\frac{2cm-6c}{a(m-1)}=\frac{2m-3}{m-1}$$
So $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=-0.5$, $d=4.5$
And one solution for your question is
$$f(x)=\frac{-0.5x+4.5}{x-1}$$

Comment: I believe your basic transformation should be $$f\left(1 - \frac 4{x + 1}\right) + f\left(1 \color{red}{+} \frac 2{x + 1}\right)$$ ... just a 1 line typo since your next line is correct...

Comment: Thank you for your correction XD! I have  refined my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

$f\left(\dfrac{x-3}{x+1}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{x+3}{x+1}\right)=x$

$f\left(1-\dfrac{4}{x+1}\right)+f\left(1+\dfrac{2}{x+1}\right)=x$

$f\left(1-\dfrac{4}{x}\right)+f\left(1+\dfrac{2}{x}\right)=x-1$

$f(1-2x)+f(1+x)=\dfrac{2}{x}-1$

$f(3-2x)+f(x)=\dfrac{2}{x-1}-1~......(1)$

$f(3-2(3-2x))+f(3-2x)=\dfrac{2}{3-2x-1}-1$

$f(4x-3)+f(3-2x)=-\dfrac{1}{x-1}-1~......(2)$

$(2)-(1)$ :

$f(4x-3)-f(x)=-\dfrac{3}{x-1}$

$f(4(4^x+1)-3)-f(4^x+1)=-\dfrac{3}{4^x+1-1}$

$f(4^{x+1}+1)-f(4^x+1)=-3\times4^{-x}$

$f(4^x+1)=\Theta(x)+4^{1-x}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$f(x)=\Theta(\log_4(x-1))+\dfrac{4}{x-1}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period